# TFS + Visual Studio 2010 + Getting the name of an extracting user

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on a WinForm project in my company with 3 other developers.
We are working within Visual Studio 2010 and files in the project are managed by an instance of TFS.
When a file is extracted by a user then a small icon representing a man is displayed at the left hand of the file name in the project tree view.
I would appreciate a way to get the name of the user who has extracted a file.

I currently try to extract a file already extracted to get the extracting user's name.
Then an error message is displayed and contains the extracting user's name.

Comment: Admittedly I don't know TFS very well, but I didn't see any references to *extract.*  Did you mean get the name of the user who checked out/locked a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see which user(s) have an item checked out, along with lots of other information, using Source Control Explorer. Here's the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181370(VS.100).aspx.